# How to access Controls name used on contentview in content page

Tags: xaml, user-controls, xamarin.forms

I am using usercontrol in xamarin.forms and I need to access controls name used on ContentView in Content Page. I want to do Visibility of the controls true/false on button clicks. I am getting click events but need to access controls names to like labels, entries.

Comment: Please show the code you have for accessing the controls

Comment: you should put some progress here, see my answer down below!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using?

```
Button myButton = [YourCONTENTVIEW].FindByName<Button>("myButton");
```

Answer (score -1):

- First of all if you are using XAML PLC you should create your ContentPage and for each control that you wanna access, needs to set a propertie name.

  ```
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       BackgroundColor="White"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       x:Class="Gone.UsersXaml.ChatPage">

  <Label Text="Hello" x:Name = "MyLabel"/>
  <Button x:Name = "MyButton"/>
  </ContentPage>
  ```
- And then in your Code-Behind goes like...

  ```
  public partial class SignupPage : ContentPage
  {
     public SignupPage()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyLabel.Text = "New Text Label";
        MyButton.IsVisible = true;
     }
  }
  ```